# Can a moving camera read the QR code?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, qr-code

I wish to use QR code as a landmark in my project, where the phone's camera is moving. I am using an Android phone. So I am wondering how fast can a QR code be read and recognized?

Normal use requires quite a long time. I think around 2~3 seconds.

Can the recognition process be accelerated to say 0.5 second?

Is it possible for a **moving** camera to catch the QR code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried this library? https://code.google.com/p/zxing/

From my experience, if the camera is in focus it recognize the QR code is 1 second or less.

Comment: It's about 50 ms even. But this is not the limiting factor even, more like shutter speed

Answer (score 1):

It depends on sensitivity (ISO), shutter speed, and aperture of the camera.  And on external aspects: luminosity, angle and relative speed of the subject QR code.